# Increase Point Size, or Change Shape of GGplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a plot seen below, and want to either increase the point size, change the shape, or preferably, make it one continuous point.

When I try and use geom_point, it removes the color from the points, but it does make them larger.

```
library(rayshader)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(scales)
library(rgdal)
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
#Data from NY Times
mask = read_csv("mask-use-by-county_ed.csv")

maskgg = ggplot(mask) +
  geom_raster(aes(x=ALWAYS_MASK,y=PERCENT_COLLEGE,fill=COVID_CASES)) +
  scale_x_continuous("ALWAYS WEARS MASK",expand=c(0,0),breaks=seq(0,100,10)) +
  scale_y_continuous("PERCENT COLLEGE",expand=c(0,0),breaks=seq(0,60,10),limits=c(0,60)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  ggtitle("COVID CASES BY MASK USE AND EDUCATION") +
  labs(caption = "Data Source: NY TIMES")
maskgg

plot_gg(maskgg, multicore=TRUE,height=5,width=6,scale=500)
```

3D Plot of Data:
[image: 3D Plot of Data]

[image]

Comment: When you use `geom_color()` and make sure to set the `color=` aesthetic rather than the `fill=` aesthetic.

Comment: Have you tried simply setting `size=2` in your geom? `geom_point()` also seems more appropriate here (with `color` rather than `fill` as MrFlick says). You can also try the parameter `width`.